# How would a multithreaded program be more energy efficient?

Tags: multithreading, optimization, concurrency, performance

In its [Energy-Efficient Software Guidelines](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/energy-efficient-software-guidelines/) Intel suggests that programs are designed multithreaded for better energy efficiency.

I don't get it. Suppose I have a quad core processor that can switch off unused cores. Suppose my code is perfectly parallelizeable (synchronization overhead is negligible).

If I use only one core I burn one core for one hour, if I use four cores I burn four cores for 15 minutes - the same amount of core-hours either way. Where's the saving?

Comment: I wonder if they're factoring in the fact that the rest of the computer has to be powered for those extra 45 minutes too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it has to do with a non-linear relation between CPU utilization and power consumption. So if you can spread 100% CPU utilization over 4 CPUs each will have 25% utilization - and say 12% consumption.

This is especially true when dynamic CPU scaling is used according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_power_dissipation) the power drain of a CPU is `P = C(V^2)F`. When a CPU is running faster it requires higher voltages - and that 'to the power of 2' becomes crucial. Furthermore the voltage will be a function of F (which means F can be solved for V) giving something like `P = C(F^2)F`. Thus by spreading the load over 4 CPUs (running at 100% capacity at that frequency) you can mitigate the cost for the same work.

We can make F a function of L (load) at 100% of one core (as it would be in your OS), so:

```
F = 1000 + L/100 * 500 = 1000 + 5L
p = C((1000 + 5L)^2)(1000 + 5L) = C(1000 + 5L)^3
```

Now that we can relate load (L) to the power consumption we can see the characteristics of the power consumption given everything on one core:

```
p = C(1000 + 5L)^3
p = 1000000000 + 15000000L + 75000L^2 + 125L^3
```

Or spread over 4 cores:

```
p = 4C(1000 + (5/4)L)^3
p = 4000000000 + 15000000L + 18750.4L^2 + 7.5L^3
```

Notice the factors in front of the L^2 and L^3.

Comment: Actually as a matter of fact to save energy it's way better on modern x86 CPUs to completely power up the core and get the work done as fast as possible and then go back into the highest energy saving mode than doing the work with only a fraction of power.

Comment: @Voo: I don't quite get your point. Do you agree with the answer or not?

Comment: @Voo the math doesn't lie. "Notice the factors in front of the L^2 and L^3." When you bring it time, the equation would basically turn into `p = 4000000000 + 15000000TL + 18750.4TL^2 + 7.5TL^3` or something similar. Hey, it was a theory; I guess only the Intel engineers who came up with this could indicate why exactly.

Comment: @Voo I think you are correct.
JonathanDickinson: The arithmetic argument is persuasive, but also based on flawed assumptions.  Frequency and voltage do not change dynamically as the argument requires.  When a processor is half-loaded, it takes too long to get slow and its voltage to drop, basically it runs more inefficiently.
Disregard Intel recommendations, they might be pure marketing.
What applies to a single computer does not apply to whole server farms, I would agree with the Google corporation it is more power efficient to have lots of slow and "cool" processors instead of a few hot.

Comment: @Jonathan A bit late, but anyhow. Those formulas are *approximations* which Intel engineers didn't come up with but which just follow from the way transistors classically work and are described. The problem is that it's just an approximation and that in reality the formula is by far not as easy. If you try empirical tests you'll see that this is only a really coarse approximation since at least 45nm processes - static consumption and leakage is becoming dominant more and more and your even more simplified formula completely ignores those!

Comment: cont. Basically in practice with power gating and everything what you want is to finish the work as quickly as possible and then go to one of the low power states with much lower static consumption and less leakage - the fact that your dynamic power consumption (basically the cost of transistors switching, which becomes lower the smaller the process is) is higher becomes less and less important.

Answer (score 4):

During that one hour, the one core isn't the only thing you keep running.

Answer (score 3):

You burn 4 times energy with 4 cores but you do 4 times more work too! If, as you said, the synchro is negligible and the work is parallelizable, you'll spend 4 times less time.

Using multiple threads can save energy when you have i/o waits. One thread can wait while other threads can perform other computations; instead of having your application idle.

Answer (score 3):

A CPU is one part of a computer. It has fans, a motherboard, hard drives, graphics card, RAM etc, lets call this the BASE. If your doing scientific computing (i.e., a compute cluster) you are powering many computers. If you are powering 100's of BASE's anyway, why not allow those BASES to have multiple physical CPU's on them so those CPU's can share the resources of the BASE, physical and logical.

Now INTEL's marketing blurb probably also depends on the fact that these days, each CPU wafer contains multiple cores. Powering multiple physical CPU's is different to powering a single physical cpu with multiple cores.

So if amount of work done per unit of power is the benchmark in question, then modern CPU's performing highly parallel tasks then yes you get more bang for your buck, compared with the previous generation of processors. As not only can you get more cores / cpu, it is also ***common*** to get BASE's which can take multiple CPU's.

One may easily assert that one top-end system can now house the processing power of 8-16 singl-cpu single-core CPU's of the past (assuming that in this hypothetical case, that on the new system and the older generation system, each core has the same processing power ).

Answer (score 2):

If a program is multithreaded that doesn't mean that it would use more cores. It just means that more tasks are dealt with in the same time so the overall processor time is shorter.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 reasons, two of which have already been pointed out:

1. More overall time means that other (non-CPU) components need to run longer, even if the net calculation for the CPU remains the same
2. More threads mean more things are done at the same time (because stalls are used for something useful), again the overall real time is reduced.
3. The CPU power consumption for running the same calculations on one core *is not the same*. Intel CPUs have a built-in clock boosting for single-core usage (I forgot the marketing buzzword for it). A higher clock means dysproportionally more power consumption and dysproportionally more heat, which again requires the fan to spin faster, too.

So in summary, you consume more power with the CPU and more power for cooling the CPU for a longer time, and you run other components for a longer time, too.

As a 4th reason, one could allege (note that this is only an assumption!) that Intel CPUs are hyperthreaded, and since hyperthreaded cores share some resources, running two threads at once is more efficient than running one thread twice as long.

Comment: I'm not so sure about #3. Sure you get higher frequencies, but that's not disproportional since it scales linearly compared to voltage and so far Intel's power saving strategy was always to get the work done as fast as possible (ie highest possible frequencies and all) and then go back to sleep.

Comment: @Voo: It is certainly true, as easily verified with your computer plugged into a digital electric meter (an APC UPS will -slightly less accurately- display the same info in the utility program). My computer consumes 97W (+/- 0.1W) at 1.971GHz and 156W (+/- 0.1W) at 2705GHz (100% CPU, no graphics, no disk activity). 2705/1971 = 1.37, and 156/97 = 1.60. Obviously 1.6 > 1.3.

Comment: Well how did you increase the clock speed? Not impossible that your voltage was also slightly increased. Also an increase in frequency of 37% resulting in 61% more power is still quite possibly on a linear scale.

Comment: Also the real comparison is energy spent at full power + rest of time spent in the highest power saving setting vs. spending more time in some middle ground. If you look at how Intel handles this situation, they seem to agree that #1 is "better".

Comment: A. Munshi quotes an IEEE article by Chandrakasan Potkonjak et al. in his "OpenCL Programming Guide" book, coming to the same conclusion that the same processing done by several slower cores is more efficient than by a single faster one, for the same reasons. Higher C in favour of lower f and V, respecively are more than linearly (indeed more than quadratically) better for power efficiency.